# MissingRegistraton error when trying to send data to GCM

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for this question.

I'm using a PHP server and is trying to send PushNotifications to my Android app. But when I'm trying out my code in the browser I get this error: "Error=MissingRegistration".

Here is the code that I run:

```
registration_ids = array($regId);
        $message = array(
            'hangMessage' => $message,
            'userId' => $user_id
            );

        $result = $gcm->send_notification($registration_ids, $message);
```

And this is the code that I call:

```
$url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $regisration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
        );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type= application/json',
        );

    //Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    //Execute psot
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result == false){
        die('Curl failed: ' . Curl_error($ch));
    }

    //Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

The Request doesn't even come all the way to the server according to the Google APIs Console Report system.

Anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request should look like this :

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Therefore I believe the error might be in this line :

```
'Content-Type= application/json'
```

Try to change the `=` to `:`.

Since the content type header is invalid, the GCM server may assume a default value for the content type (which might be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`, in which case the Registration ID requires a different key, which would explain the `MissingRegistration` error).

BTW, the fact that you get a `MissingRegistraton` error means that the request does reach the GCM server. GCM requests are not logged in the Google APIs Console Report system.

Comment: what is the different key requried for UTF8?